# What is the correct way to move key-value contents from the first map to the second(value-key) map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, move-semantics

I am trying to count the most common words in text, so firstly i am filling the map of <word, count>, secondly I am trying to move the contents of the map <word, count> to the multimap<count, word>. But there is the problem: node type of STL maps/hashes are <const Key, Value>. I have tried to const_cast, it worked, but it seems ugly and UB'ly. Are there any another ways to move the contents?

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> words;
    std::multimap<std::size_t, std::string> sorted_ordered_words;

    std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin}, {}, [&](const std::string& str)
    {
        ++words[str];
    });

    std::transform(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(words)),
                    std::make_move_iterator(std::end(words)),
                    std::inserter(sorted_ordered_words, std::end(sorted_ordered_words)),
                    [](decltype (words)::value_type && v)
    {
        return std::make_pair(v.second, std::move(const_cast<std::string&>(v.first)));
    });
    for (const auto &[count, word] : sorted_ordered_words)
    {
        std::cout << count << " - " << word << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to put the result in a multimap ? is there any other reasons besides sorting by occurences ?

Comment: @Maaddy for printing the results in the ascending order

Comment: You can instead store each pair of <count, word> in a vector and sort it. it's much simpler, has the same time complexity and might be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

A well defined way to move the string from the original container is to [extract](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/extract) the node it is in first. That exposes a non-const reference to the key.

```cpp
for (auto it = words.begin(); it != words.end();) {
    auto copy = it;
    ++it;

    auto node = words.extract(copy);

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::move(node.key())), std::string&&>);
    sorted_ordered_words.emplace(node.mapped(), std::move(node.key()));
}
```

Using `const_cast` is definitely UB because the keys are just moved from but are still in the map, violating internal constraints (all strings are the same, `""`, when they should all be unique). This could lead to crashes in the destructor for example.

---

If it's just for printing in order, you don't need to build a multimap. It's faster to just sort a vector of pairs rather than inserting into a multimap one by one.

```cpp
std::vector<decltype(words)::value_type*> vec;
vec.reserve(words.size());
std::transform(words.begin(), words.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](auto& v) { return &v; });
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto* l, auto* r) {
    return l->second < r->second;
});


for (const auto* item : vec) {
    const auto& [word, count] = *item;
    std::cout << count << " - " << word << std::endl;
}
```

You could also use `std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, const std::string&>>` and sort by `.first`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is the reason of copying iterator and then incrementing it?

Comment: @exoze Because `extract` invalidates the iterator, so you can't increment after. Though this could easily also be written as `auto node = words.extract(it++);`